# Some small error I'm unable to identify and not even ChatGPT is able to solve

Tags: python

So this is the problem [Text Justification](https://leetcode.com/problems/text-justification/?envType=study-plan-v2&envId=top-interview-150) and I've solved it for most test cases (24/29).

But on the test case:

```
["ask","not","what","your","country","can","do","for","you",
 "ask","what","you","can","do","for","your","country"]
```

My output:

```
["ask   not   what","your country can","do  for  you ask",
 "what  you can do","for your country "]
```

Expected:

```
["ask   not   what","your country can","do  for  you ask",
 "what  you can do","for your country"]
```

How do I get rid of the last space in case of the words in the last line being exactly equal (along with single spaces) to the char length limit as given in the question.

I've tried absolutely everything.

```
class Solution:
    def full_justify(self, w: List[str], m: int) -> List[str]:
        a = []
        t = []
        i = 0

        while i < len(w):
            n = m

            while i < len(w) and n >= len(w[i]) + len(t):
                n -= len(w[i])
                t.append(w[i])
                i += 1

            lenc = sum(len(s) for s in t)

            if i < len(w) and len(t) > 1:
                spaces = (m - lenc) // (len(t) - 1)
                extra_spaces = (m - lenc) % (len(t) - 1)
                line = t[0]

                for j in range(1, len(t)):
                    spaces_to_add = spaces + (1 if j <= extra_spaces else 0)
                    line += ' ' * spaces_to_add + t[j]

                a.append(line)    
            else:
                line = ' '.join(t) + ' ' * (m - lenc)

                if len(line) > m and line[-1] == ' ':
                    line = line[:-1]

                a.append(line)     
   
            t.clear()
        return a
```

Comment: Add a .strip() for each assembled line?

Comment: @Barmar you made it less readable... Please add linebreaks

Answer (score 1):

Alright so the answer was pretty simple but it troubled me later on as well when the added spaces in the end was even greater than one. It was hole I've been digging for my own self, hehe.
Here's the final solution I implemented:

```
class Solution:
def fullJustify(self, w: List[str], m: int) -> List[str]:
    a = []
    t = []
    i = 0

    while i < len(w):
        n = m

        while i < len(w) and n >= len(w[i]) + len(t):
            n -= len(w[i])
            t.append(w[i])

            i += 1
        lenc = sum(len(s) for s in t)

        if i < len(w) and len(t) > 1:
            spaces = (m - lenc) // (len(t) - 1)
            extra_spaces = (m - lenc) % (len(t) - 1)
            line = t[0]

            for j in range(1, len(t)):
                spaces_to_add = spaces + (1 if j <= extra_spaces else 0)
                line += ' ' * spaces_to_add + t[j]
            a.append(line)

        else:
            line = ' '.join(t) + ' ' * (m - lenc)
            if len(line) > m and line[-1] == ' ':
                line = line[:-1]
            a.append(line)        
        t.clear()

    last_line = a[-1]

    while len(last_line) > m and last_line[-1] == ' ':
        last_line = last_line[:-1] 
    a[-1] = last_line

    return a
```

Instead of checking the line before sending it to the final list, I simply checked the last line in the list to finally get rid of the error I was facing.

Comment: Yeah ofcourse simpler solutions exist. I was looking to see why this solution wasn't working the way it should've. Thank anyway!